# dialog Upnp make a connected device menu

Tags: android-listview

How do I choose in setconnectdevice?

LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);//自定義一個佈局文件
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

```
    ListView listView = new ListView(mContext);
    listView.setFadingEdgeLength(0);

    List<Map<String, Object>> deviceList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < remoteDeviceList.size(); i++) {
        Map<String, Object> nameMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        //標題
        nameMap.put("ModelName", 
        remoteDeviceList.get(i).getDetails().getModelDetails().getModelName());
        //內容
        nameMap.put("Model", remoteDeviceList.get(i));
        deviceList.add(nameMap);
    }
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(mContext,
            deviceList, R.layout.listview,
            new String[]{"ModelName"}, new int[]{R.id.tv_popup_title});

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    linearLayout.addView(listView);//往這個佈局中加入listview
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
    .setTitle("投放到").setView(linearLayout);
    dialog.setNegativeButton("取消", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    }).create();
    dialog.show();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_popup_title);

            RemoteDevice choiceDevice = (RemoteDevice) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            ServiceManager.getInstance().setConnectedDevice(**choiceDevice**);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have solved my problem。thanks!!